# Modifying lines in a file selected by their position relative to a marker

Tags: regex, perl

I am stuck at one point in my code and need some help.

I have a file which looks something like this:

```
some lines
some lines
LABEL:
NOP ABC some text - line 1
NOP ABC some text - line 2
NOP ABC some text - line 3
NOP ABC some text - line 4
NOP ABC some text - line 5
NOP ABC some text - line 6
NOP ABC some text - line 7  
NOP ABC some text - line 8 
NOP ABC some text - line 9 
NOP ABC some text - line 10
NOP ABC some text - line 11
```

Now, my requrirement is, once the `LABEL:` is matched, I have to skip the next line (line 1) and modify the next two lines which are line 2 and 3 replacing `ABC` with `DEF ABC`. Then skip the next 2 lines, 4 and 5, and modify next two lines, 6 and 7 in the same way. Then again skip the next 2 lines, 8 and 9, and modify the following 2 lines, 10 and 11 etc.

I can't figure out how to achieve this. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
while (<>) {

   my $cur_line = $_;
   my $ctv_line = "";

   if ($cur_line =~ /^LABEL/) {

      print "$cur_line";

      my $next_line = <>;
      print "$next_line\n";

      for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
         if ($next_line =~ s/NOP\s+ABC/NOP DEF ABC/) {
            $ctv_line = $next_line;
            print "$ctv_line";
         }
      }

      print "$next_line";
      print "next_line";

      for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
         if ($next_line =~ s/NOP\s+ABC/NOP DEF ABC/) {
            $ctv_line = $next_line;
            print "$ctv_line";
         }
      }

   }
   else {
      print "$cur_line";
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the variable number of blank lines in your example data?

Comment: those blank lines were accidentally added while was trying to format my question. Apologies..

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your own code is that the majority executes only on the line containing the label, because it is within `if ($cur_line =~ /^LABEL/) { ... }` whereas the lines that you want to modify come *after* that line.

This is most straighforwardly done if you make a note, using the value of `$.`, of the line number that the label falls on. Thereafter you can find the line number relative to the label by subtraction, and, since the modifications have a pattern in groups of four, the modulus operator `%` will tell you whether to make a subtitution or not.

*Note that this is now modified according to your comment, where you say you want to skip two lines out of every ten.*

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt';

my $label_line;

while (<$fh>) {
   $label_line = $. if /LABEL:/;
   if ($label_line) {
      s/ABC/DEF ABC/ if ( $. - $label_line ) % 10 >= 2;
   }
   print;
}
```

**output**

```
some lines
some lines
LABEL:
NOP ABC some text - line 1
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 2
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 3
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 4
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 5
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 6
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 7  
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 8 
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 9 
NOP ABC some text - line 10
NOP ABC some text - line 11
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 12
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 13
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 14
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 15
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 16
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 17
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 18
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 19
NOP ABC some text - line 20
NOP ABC some text - line 21
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 22
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 23
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 24
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 25
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 26
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 27
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 28
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 29
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. However, in my real file (I was just trying to show an example), I have to skip the next line after label, modify next 8 lines by DEF ABC, skip next 2 lines and again modify next 8 lines. Can you please how to achieve this. Sorry but I am little new to Perl

Comment: It sure does. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to determine the line number after the matched label:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $range = /LABEL/ .. undef) {
        s/(?=ABC)/DEF / if ($range - 1) % 4 > 1;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
some lines
some lines
LABEL:
NOP ABC some text - line 1
NOP ABC some text - line 2
NOP ABC some text - line 3
NOP ABC some text - line 4
NOP ABC some text - line 5
NOP ABC some text - line 6
NOP ABC some text - line 7  
NOP ABC some text - line 8 
NOP ABC some text - line 9 
NOP ABC some text - line 10
NOP ABC some text - line 11
```

Outputs:

```
some lines
some lines
LABEL:
NOP ABC some text - line 1
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 2
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 3
NOP ABC some text - line 4
NOP ABC some text - line 5
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 6
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 7  
NOP ABC some text - line 8 
NOP ABC some text - line 9 
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 10
NOP DEF ABC some text - line 11
```

#### Update for roaming specification

You stated in a comment the following:

> thanks for the feedback. However, in my real file (I was just trying to show an example), *I have to skip the next line after label, modify next 8 lines by DEF ABC, skip next 2 lines and again modify next 8 lines.* Can you please how to achieve this. Sorry but I am little new to Perl

This is easily accepted by changing the script to the following:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $range = /LABEL/ .. undef) {
        s/(?=ABC)/DEF / if ($range - 1) % 10 > 1;
    }
    print;
}
```